# $(this).parent().attr('id') gets '[object window]' not element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I'm trying to get the ID attribute of the clicked element, sounds simple enough, but I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .posttag- Window]`

Here's the code I've written

`$('#blogposts_filters > li > a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        thistag = toString($this.parent().attr('id')).substring(7);
    console.log(thistag) //returns [Object Window] if substring(0)
    // Filter through
    $('#blogposts_list .posttag-' + thistag).toggleClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Tried a few different things but I'm pretty new to js/jquery and kinda stumped.
Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: show relevant html as well

Comment: What is the toString() function? Seems like it returns `this` while being called in the global context.

Comment: '#blogposts_list...' is an id selector, maybe the right format is '#blogposts_list.posttag-xxx' without the white space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, unless you've redefined the `toString` function to be something else (in which case we need to see it!), you probably don't actually need it. Numbers will cast themselves to strings on their own, e.g. `'string' + 123 == 'string123'`.

Additionally, `toString` is actually a method! So what you're doing is really calling it on the global, and `window.toString()` always returns `[Object Window]`. Not what you want.

So, just use `.attr('id')` and trust JavaScript to convert the number into a string:

```
$('#blogposts_filters > li > a').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        thistag = $this.parent().attr('id');
    // Filter through
    $('#blogposts_list .posttag-' + thistag).toggleClass('hidden');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, just removed the toString method and all is good. Thanks for the explanation too, very helpful. Can see the wip here www.matt-willett.co.uk/preview

Answer (score 2):

For getting id of particular element on click event...simply use this

```
$('#blogposts_filters > li > a').click(function(e) {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```